# Dos gráficos interactivos en una sola ventana con matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo un gráfico de velas ohlc que me funciona bien, está en modo estático e interactivo, en el estático puedo mostrar las velas y además graficar encima otro que serían los cierres así:

[image: Gráfica estática con cierres]

El modo interactivo logra graficar cada vela determinado tiempo, pero también quiero que grafique la linea al mismo tiempo y no lo logro, de hecho logro graficar ambos pero por separado, ¿cómo podría unirlos?

Estos son mis datos y mis códigos:

```
datos_tratados.csv

201611010000,1.096100,1.096140,1.096100,1.096130
201611010001,1.096130,1.096200,1.096130,1.096160
201611010002,1.096150,1.096210,1.096140,1.096150
201611010003,1.096140,1.096170,1.096130,1.096140
201611010004,1.096150,1.096220,1.096150,1.096220
201611010005,1.096220,1.096320,1.096220,1.096300
201611010006,1.096300,1.096340,1.096300,1.096340
201611010007,1.096350,1.096360,1.096320,1.096340
201611010008,1.096360,1.096370,1.096350,1.096370
201611010009,1.096370,1.096410,1.096340,1.096360
201611010010,1.096360,1.096380,1.096360,1.096360
201611010011,1.096370,1.096370,1.096370,1.096370
201611010012,1.096370,1.096370,1.096300,1.096320
201611010013,1.096320,1.096390,1.096300,1.096380
201611010014,1.096380,1.096410,1.096360,1.096380
201611010015,1.096370,1.096370,1.096350,1.096360
201611010016,1.096350,1.096350,1.096320,1.096320
201611010017,1.096290,1.096300,1.096290,1.096300
201611010018,1.096320,1.096420,1.096320,1.096420
201611010019,1.096440,1.096440,1.096350,1.096370
201611010020,1.096360,1.096530,1.096340,1.096530
201611010021,1.096500,1.096520,1.096480,1.096520
201611010022,1.096510,1.096520,1.096480,1.096510
201611010023,1.096520,1.096530,1.096490,1.096520
201611010024,1.096520,1.096610,1.096520,1.096560
201611010025,1.096570,1.096790,1.096570,1.096790
201611010026,1.096770,1.096830,1.096660,1.096820
201611010027,1.096810,1.096850,1.096800,1.096810
201611010028,1.096790,1.096790,1.096680,1.096690
201611010029,1.096690,1.096700,1.096680,1.096700
```

Programa principal modo estático con velas + linea, modo interactivo solo velas:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import date2num
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker


def grafico_estatico():
    style.use('dark_background')
    plt.rc('font', size=10)
    figura, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.title('EURUSD', size=15)
    plt.grid(False)

    ohlc = []
    for i in range(len(fecha)):
        agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
        ohlc.append(agregar)

    # Generar el gráfico ohlc y configuraciones básicas del eje x
    plt.plot(fecha, cierre)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.0004, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d %b %H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)

    # plt.xticks(fecha)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(25))
    plt.xlim(min(fecha) - 0.001, max(fecha) + 0.0017)
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
    plt.show()


def grafico_interactivo():
    style.use('dark_background')
    plt.rc('font', size=10)
    figura, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.grid(False)

    ohlc = []
    contador = 0
    for i in range(len(fecha)):
        agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
        ohlc.append(agregar)
        plt.title('EURUSD', size=15)
        if len(ohlc) <= 20:
            candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.00025, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
        else:
            candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc[-20:], width=0.00025, colorup='lime', colordown='red')


        xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d %b %H:%M')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        ax.yaxis.tick_right()
        plt.pause(0.1)
        if contador < len(fecha) -1:
            plt.cla()
        contador += 1
    plt.show()

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                                 converters={0: convertir})

modo = input("Modo del gráfico - e/i: ")
while modo != "e" and modo != "i":
    print("Modo incorrecto")
    modo = input("Modo del gráfico: e/i")

if modo == "e":
    grafico_estatico()
else:
    grafico_interactivo()
```

Programa que únicamente grafica las lineas tipo: `plt.plot`

```
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.finance import date2num
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                                 converters={0: convertir})
lista_cierres = []
for i in range(len(fecha)):
    lista_cierres.append(np.array(cierre[i]))
    plt.plot(lista_cierres)
    plt.pause(0.5)
plt.show()
```

¿Cómo puedo unirlos en la función `grafico_interactivo()` para graficar de modo interactivo velas y lineas al mismo tiempo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el interactivo no estás metiendo un `plt.plot` para meter los valores en línea. Sobre tu programa principal puedes añadir lo siguiente (5 líneas con comentario `#### AÑADIDO`) para que vaya actualizando también la línea:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.finance import date2num
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as md
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker


def grafico_estatico():
    style.use('dark_background')
    plt.rc('font', size=10)
    figura, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.title('EURUSD', size=15)
    plt.grid(False)

    ohlc = []
    for i in range(len(fecha)):
        agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
        ohlc.append(agregar)

    # Generar el gráfico ohlc y configuraciones básicas del eje x
    plt.plot(fecha, cierre)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.0004, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
    xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d %b %H:%M')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)

    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)

    # plt.xticks(fecha)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(25))
    plt.xlim(min(fecha) - 0.001, max(fecha) + 0.0017)
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.01, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
    plt.show()


def grafico_interactivo():
    style.use('dark_background')
    plt.rc('font', size=10)
    figura, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.grid(False)

    ohlc = []
    line = []                          #### AÑADIDO
    fech = []                          #### AÑADIDO
    contador = 0
    for i in range(len(fecha)):
        agregar = fecha[i], apertura[i], alto[i], bajo[i], cierre[i]
        ohlc.append(agregar)
        line.append(cierre[i])         #### AÑADIDO
        fech.append(fecha[i])          #### AÑADIDO
        plt.title('EURUSD', size=15)
        if len(ohlc) <= 20:
            candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc, width=0.00025, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
        else:
            candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc[-20:], width=0.00025, colorup='lime', colordown='red')
        plt.plot(fech, line)           #### AÑADIDO


        xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%d %b %H:%M')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
        ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
        ax.yaxis.tick_right()
        plt.pause(0.1)
        if contador < len(fecha) -1:
            plt.cla()
        contador += 1
    plt.show()

# Generar numpy.array con los 4 datos, convirtiendo la fecha en flotante para graficar
convertir = lambda x: date2num(datetime.strptime(x.decode("utf-8"), '%Y%m%d%H%M'))
fecha, apertura, alto, bajo, cierre = np.loadtxt('datos_tratados.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                                 converters={0: convertir})

modo = input("Modo del gráfico - e/i: ")
while modo != "e" and modo != "i":
    print("Modo incorrecto")
    modo = input("Modo del gráfico: e/i")

if modo == "e":
    grafico_estatico()
else:
    grafico_interactivo()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó a la perfección.